# How to output each line in a file which contains any of the strings in a list

Tags: python, exception, file-io, io, filehandle

What I have so far:

```
def FileSearch(filename, items):
    try:
        filehandle = open( filename, "r" )
        linenumber = 0
        for line in filename:
            linenumber +=1
            for item in items:
                if item in line:
                    print("%2i - %s" %( linenumber, line), end="")
    except IOError:
        print("Error file cannot be read or file does not exist")
        print("Please try again")
```

I'm trying to print lines, preceded by their linenumber, that contain any of the strings contained in the list 'items'. So it would output something like this:

```
>>>FileSearch("textfile",["this","and","is"])
2 - this is the 2nd line
4 - hello and goodbye
5 - this is a very basic example
```

But when I run the program I'm not even getting an error, nothing happens it just runs to the next line.
I'd appreciate any help.
I was wondering also if there was a way to print the lines in numerical order or would the program do it itself here?

Comment: Do you want lines where more than one match is found, to be printed more than once?

Comment: no i dont want any duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting an output, neither an error, because you are iterating not over the lines of the file, but rather over the characters of the `filename`. Change this line:

```
for line in filename:
```

To this one:

```
for line in filehandle:
```

Comment: it worked! thank you, but it outputs duplicates, how would i avoid them?

Comment: @DecafOyster208 the output in your example is 'duplicating' because your `items` contains two strings (`this` and `is`) that are both in line 2 and line 5. If you run your function like this: `FileSearch("textfile",["this","and"])`, you'll see that it's not duplicating.
But if you want to stop the loop after the first match, just add `break` after the `print("%2i - %s" %( linenumber, line), end="")` statement.